# JSON Write 1 Dimensional Array

Tags: vb.net, json.net

JSON as follows:

```
 "Items": {
 "defaultActionClass": "Weaponclass",
 "ItemObjects": [
   {
     "Id": "M16",
     "Name": "EM16",
     "Description": "Some Description",
     "Icon": "Icons/pictures/1.png",
     "AnimationSet": "Set1",
     "Type": "Weapon",
     "EquipmentClass": "Hands",
     "SlotsCount": 2,
     "Weight": 1,
     "AP": 1,
     "BurstFire": 1,
     "AutoFire": 0,
     "EffectiveRange": 8.0,
     "MuzzleVelocity": 2.5,
     "BaseAccuracy": 100.0,
     "Mobility": 6.0,
     "Damage": 30,
     "DamageFalloff": 30,
     "AmmoClips": [
       "AmmoClip556NATOx30"
     ]
   },
```

The portion I am struggling with is the:

```
"AmmoClips": [
  "AmmoClip556NATOx30"
]
```

I can read and write the rest of the file but this one I can't find a solution for this section

I am reading it via:

```
Public Property AmmoClips As String()
Ammunition = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AmmoClips").ToString)
```

This returns:

```
[
  "AmmoClip556NATOx30"
]
```

I then attempt to use the following to write it back, and I have tried dozens of different methods with no luck.

```
    Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim GamePath As String
    Dim Gamefile As String
    Dim strjson As String
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim NextCount As Integer
    Dim Ammunition
    Dim AmmoOutput



    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        GamePath = "E:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Jagged Alliance Flashback\game_Data\StreamingAssets\Original\Data\"
        Gamefile = "Items\Weapons.json"
        strjson = File.ReadAllText(GamePath & Gamefile)
        'RichTextBox1.Text = strjson
        Dim root As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(strjson)
        Dim ID As List(Of String) = root.Items.ItemObjects.Select(Of String)(Function(tp) tp.Id).ToList()
        cmbWeaponID.DataSource = ID
        NextCount = ID.Count + 1
    End Sub



    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        'sb = sb.AppendLine
        'sb = sb.Append("""AmmoClip44Magnumx6""").AppendLine
        'sb = sb.AppendLine
        'Dim sbarray As New JRaw
        'sbarray = sb
        AmmoOutput = New String() {Ammunition, Ammunition}
        ' MsgBox(AmmoOutput)
        Dim sJsonObj As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(File.ReadAllText(GamePath & Gamefile))
        sJsonObj.Items.ItemObjects.Add(New ItemObject With {
        .Id = NextCount,
        .Name = txtName.Text,
        .Description = txtDescription.Text,
        .Icon = "Icons/Weapons/M16.png",
        .AnimationSet = "Rifle",
        .Type = "Weapon",
        .EquipmentClass = "Hands",
        .SlotsCount = txtSlotCount.Text,
        .Weight = txtWeight.Text,
        .AP = txtAPtoFire.Text,
        .BurstFire = txtBurstFire.Text,
        .AutoFire = txtAutoFire.Text,
        .EffectiveRange = txtEffectiveRange.Text,
        .MuzzleVelocity = txtMuzzleVelocity.Text,
        .BaseAccuracy = txtBaseAccuracy.Text,
        .Mobility = txtMobility.Text,
        .Damage = txtDamage.Text,
        .DamageFalloff = txtDamageFalloff.Text,
        .AmmoClips = AmmoOutput
            })

        'Serialize to JSON string.
        Dim settings As New JsonSerializerSettings
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        Dim strAddJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sJsonObj, settings)

        ' Write to file.
        File.WriteAllText(GamePath & Gamefile, strAddJson)

    End Sub


    Private Sub cmbWeaponID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndexChanged
        'cmbWeaponID.Items.Add(weaponjson.SelectToken("Items").SelectTokens("ItemObjects[0].Id"))
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(strjson)
        Dim Type As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Type"))
        Dim Name As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Name"))
        Dim Description As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Description"))
        Dim Icon As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Icon"))
        Dim AnimationSet As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AnimationSet"))
        Dim SlotsCount As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].SlotsCount"))
        Dim Weight As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Weight"))
        Dim APCost As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AP"))
        Dim BurstFire As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].BurstFire"))
        Dim AutoFire As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AutoFire"))
        Dim EffectiveRange As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].EffectiveRange"))
        Dim MuzzleVelocity As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].MuzzleVelocity"))
        Dim BaseAccuracy As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].BaseAccuracy"))
        Dim Mobility As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Mobility"))
        Dim Damage As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Damage"))
        Dim DamageFalloff As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].DamageFalloff"))
        If AnimationSet = "Rifle" Or AnimationSet = "Handgun" Then
            Dim Ammunition As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AmmoClips[0]"))
            'MsgBox(Ammunition)
            txtName.Text = Name
            txtDescription.Text = Description
            'picIcon.Image.
            lblAnimationSet.Text = AnimationSet
            txtSlotCount.Text = SlotsCount
            txtWeight.Text = Weight
            txtAPtoFire.Text = APCost
            If BurstFire = 1 Then
                chkBurstFire.Checked = True
            Else
                chkBurstFire.Checked = False
            End If
            If AutoFire = 1 Then
                chkAutoFire.Checked = True
            Else
                chkAutoFire.Checked = False
            End If
            txtBurstFire.Text = BurstFire
            txtAutoFire.Text = AutoFire
            txtEffectiveRange.Text = EffectiveRange
            txtMuzzleVelocity.Text = MuzzleVelocity
            txtBaseAccuracy.Text = BaseAccuracy
            txtMobility.Text = Mobility
            txtDamage.Text = Damage
            txtDamageFalloff.Text = DamageFalloff
            txtAmmunition.Text = Ammunition
        ElseIf AnimationSet = "Unarmed" Or AnimationSet = "Knife" Or AnimationSet = "Machete" Then
            txtName.Text = Name
            txtDescription.Text = Description
            'picIcon.Image.
            lblAnimationSet.Text = AnimationSet
            txtSlotCount.Text = SlotsCount
            txtWeight.Text = Weight
            txtAPtoFire.Text = APCost
            If BurstFire = 1 Then
                chkBurstFire.Checked = True
            Else
                chkBurstFire.Checked = False
            End If
            If AutoFire = 1 Then
                chkAutoFire.Checked = True
            Else
                chkAutoFire.Checked = False
            End If
            txtEffectiveRange.Text = EffectiveRange
            txtMuzzleVelocity.Text = MuzzleVelocity
            txtBaseAccuracy.Text = BaseAccuracy
            txtMobility.Text = Mobility
            txtDamage.Text = Damage
            txtDamageFalloff.Text = DamageFalloff
            txtAmmunition.Text = Nothing
        ElseIf AnimationSet = "Throw" Then
            Dim MaxRange As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].MaxRange").ToString)
            Dim ThrowRange As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].ThrowRange").ToString)
            txtName.Text = Name
            txtDescription.Text = Description
            'picIcon.Image.
            lblAnimationSet.Text = AnimationSet
            txtSlotCount.Text = SlotsCount
            txtWeight.Text = Weight
            txtAPtoFire.Text = APCost
            If BurstFire = 1 Then
                chkBurstFire.Checked = True
            Else
                chkBurstFire.Checked = False
            End If
            If AutoFire = 1 Then
                chkAutoFire.Checked = True
            Else
                chkAutoFire.Checked = False
            End If
            txtEffectiveRange.Text = EffectiveRange
            txtMuzzleVelocity.Text = MuzzleVelocity
            txtBaseAccuracy.Text = BaseAccuracy
            txtMobility.Text = Mobility
            txtDamage.Text = Damage
            txtDamageFalloff.Text = DamageFalloff
            txtMaxRange.Text = MaxRange
            txtThrowRange.Text = ThrowRange
            txtAmmunition.Text = Nothing

        End If

    End Sub
    End Class
Public Class ItemObject
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Icon As String
    Public Property AnimationSet As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property EquipmentClass As String
    Public Property SlotsCount As Integer
    Public Property Weight As Integer
    Public Property AP As Integer
    Public Property BurstFire As Integer
    Public Property AutoFire As Integer
    Public Property EffectiveRange As Double
    Public Property MuzzleVelocity As Double
    Public Property BaseAccuracy As Double
    Public Property Mobility As Double
    Public Property Damage As Integer
    Public Property DamageFalloff As Double
    Public Property AmmoClips As List(Of String)
    Public Property Melee As Integer?
    Public Property ActionClass As String
    Public Property MaxRange As Integer?
    Public Property ThrowRange As Integer?
    Public Property RandomLootPercents As Integer?
    Public Property ExplosionType As String
End Class

Public Class Items
    Public Property defaultActionClass As String
    Public Property ItemObjects As List(Of ItemObject)
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property Items As Items
End Class
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on your latest code it looks like you have `AmmoClips` declared as a `List(Of String)` in your  `ItemObject` class.  So, in your `Button1_Click`, you need to:

1. Declare a variable as `List(Of String)`
2. `Add()` your ammunition string to that list
3. Assign the list to the `AmmoClips` property

Also, it looks like you are trying to directly assign strings from other TextBoxes to properties that are defined as `Integer` and `Double` in your `ItemObject` class.  This with cause errors as well.  You need to use `CInt` and `CDbl` to convert the values in those cases.  So, the updated `Button1_Click` code should look like this:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sJsonObj As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(File.ReadAllText(GamePath & Gamefile))

    Dim AmmoOutput As New List(Of String)
    AmmoOutput.Add(txtAmmunition.Text)

    sJsonObj.Items.ItemObjects.Add(New ItemObject With {
    .Id = NextCount,
    .Name = txtName.Text,
    .Description = txtDescription.Text,
    .Icon = "Icons/Weapons/M16.png",
    .AnimationSet = "Rifle",
    .Type = "Weapon",
    .EquipmentClass = "Hands",
    .SlotsCount = CInt(txtSlotCount.Text),
    .Weight = CInt(txtWeight.Text),
    .AP = CInt(txtAPtoFire.Text),
    .BurstFire = CInt(txtBurstFire.Text),
    .AutoFire = CInt(txtAutoFire.Text),
    .EffectiveRange = CDbl(txtEffectiveRange.Text),
    .MuzzleVelocity = CDbl(txtMuzzleVelocity.Text),
    .BaseAccuracy = CDbl(txtBaseAccuracy.Text),
    .Mobility = CDbl(txtMobility.Text),
    .Damage = CInt(txtDamage.Text),
    .DamageFalloff = CDbl(txtDamageFalloff.Text),
    .AmmoClips = AmmoOutput
        })

    'Serialize to JSON string.
    Dim settings As New JsonSerializerSettings
    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    Dim strAddJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sJsonObj, settings)

    ' Write to file.
    File.WriteAllText(GamePath & Gamefile, strAddJson)

End Sub
```

Comment: Same issue there, button that handles the addition blows up as soon as it hits .ammoclip = literally anything, string, variable, etc.

Do I need to define the AmmoClips as not a property but its own class under the ItemObejects maybe?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the full code that is "blowing up" and what error it is you're getting?  I can't see your code (other than the snippets you've posted) and it's difficult to diagnose what is going wrong if I have to guess what you're doing.

Comment: Added in everything and yes its pretty ugly since I have been trying all kinds of things.  

The actual error is  Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.  Let me take a look and I'll report back shortly.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer based on the information you gave.

Comment: Holy sweet mother of pearl that did it.  I have been searching for about 15 hours on how to handle that one line.

On the numbers etc, I haven't even had a chance to do any real checking for those issues because I could not get it to read and write the value correctly.  Appreciate the help and instructions!

Answer (score 0):

AmmoClips is an array, so probably you should add [] this to fetch its contents

```
Public Property AmmoClips As String()
Ammunition = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AmmoClips[0]").ToString)
```

Comment: The fetch works regardless, its the write that keeps killing me.

It keeps returning:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]

Comment: You're getting that error because your `Ammunition` variable is a String that contains the value `[ "AmmoClip556NATOx30" ]`. You can't assign that back to `AmmoClips` (which is a String array) -- you should fetch the entire array into a String array, make whatever changes you wish, and then assign that array back to the AmmoClips property when you write it back.

Comment: That's the part I am struggling with, how to fetch that specific item into a string array.  Honestly at this point I am not even trying to edit it, I am just trying to read it, and write it back.